# Storing email id in Cassandra using list or set

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to store 800 email id's using list or set collection in Cassandra. Can anyone give suggestion if it is advisable or not.
Our requirement is: we are trying to save the email id's and may require to fetch all 800 email id at once or any 1 email id from the list of 800 email id's depending on the select query. We also need to search a specific email id from the list. Can anyone give some suggestion.

Our requirement is: we are trying to save the email id's and may require to fetch all 800 email id at once or any 1 email id from the list of 800 email id's depending on the select query. We also need to search a specific email id from the list. Can you please give some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you need to query for specific email address it is better keep them is regular text or varchar column. But if you always use all 800 number at the same time. then either way is fine.

can you explain your use case more so we can help you better

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Navid. Our requirement is: we are trying to save the email id's and may require to fetch all 800 email id at once or any 1 email id from the list of 800 email id's depending on the select query. We also need to search a specific email id from the list. Can you please give some suggestion.

Comment: Please update the question (your original post) with this info. Better there than in a comment.

Comment: so if you need to access individual email, then it is better to use a clustering column for the id of the email. how are you distinguishing email address are you using keywords like "work","home"... I am still not clear how you would be accessing individual email

Comment: Actually i am trying to store friend list of a user. The friend list is maintained using the email id. Can you give some suggestion how should i store it. Using the friend list i am trying to render a webpage with the entire friend details.

Comment: What I can suggest is to first come up with a list of queries that you want to run against the database. Then design your tables in a way that can efficiently answer those queries. Cassandra data modeling is different from relational databases since you don't design based on your data but based on the use cases.